# pointer type dependent on if else conditional

Tags: c++, pointers, reinterpret-cast

Currently, I have code that looks like below:

```
template <class T> 
void func(const Tensor& input) {
  T* ptr = input.get_ptr();

  // we do some stuff with ptr below
}
```

I want to change the code to the following

```
template <class T> 
void func(const Tensor& input) {
  unknown_type* ptr;
  if (input.is_wrapped_int_tensor) {
    ptr = reintrepret_cast<type_depends_on_type_of_input_get_ptr*>(input.get_ptr());
  } else {
    ptr = input.get_ptr();
  }

  // we do some stuff with ptr below
}
```

Essentially, our Tensors can be floats or integers, but they're not normal C++ integers, they're custom integers, e.g., we have a `custom_int8` struct, and the `reinterpret_cast` would convert the `custom_int8*` to a regular `int8_t*`. We have code that produces `type_depends_on_type_of_input_get_ptr`.

I'm having trouble figuring out what to use for `unknown_type`. In the first snippet it was simply `T`, but here, because we have to `reinterpret_cast` if we have an int tensor, I can no longer use `T`. What can I use here that would be able to handle both cases?

I think one solution can be

```
auto* ptr = (input.is_wrapped_int_tensor ? 
    reintrepret_cast<type_depends_on_type_of_input_get_ptr*>(input.get_ptr())
    : input.get_ptr();
```

Is it possible to do this with regular if/else statements?

Comment: `std::variant<custom_int8*, T*>`

Comment: If the condition is a compile-time constant, then `if constexpr`. Otherwise not possible, since types must be known at compile-time.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat The condition is a variable determined at runtime. All `Tensor` objects are dynamically allocated

Comment: Put `// we do some stuff with ptr below` in a lambda or helper function with a `auto ptr` parameter. Then call it in both branches of the `if` instead of assigning to a `ptr` variable.